# When can I omit nouns and when can't I?

Tags: grammar, nouns

> He won fifth place in the lottery. It is his 10th already this year.
>
> --> It is his 10th ***win*** already this year.
>
> Reasons (of hair loss) can range from the simple&temporary - a vitamin deficiency - to the more complex, like an underlying health condition
>
> --> can range from the simple&temporary ***ones*** to the more complex ***ones***

In each case, the first sentence is what I read in the article and the second ones with the bold part are what I feel like they should be written.
I feel like both sentences need nouns, so if I'm guessing right(?) they are omitted in the sentence.

But I'm not sure when to omit them and when not to.

Can I just omit them when what it indicates is clear? so it depends on the writer?

Answer (score 1):

If the subject has been defined (winning or reasons) it does not have to be continually repeated. However sometimes it sounds uncomfortable

**It's his 10th win, already this year**. sounds better to me

**simple ones & temporary ones to the more complex ones** is 3 too many ones for my liking

so yes to some extent it depends on the writer

Comment: If i were to make the first sentence using the participial construction, then does "He won fifth place in the lottery, making it his 10th win already this year." sound better? than a one without win ("He won fifth place in the lottery, making it his 10th already this year.")?

Comment: And so if the nouns(subjects) are already defined in the sentence, I can omit them if I want to, right?

Comment: Although win on it's own indicates being first. Has he had 10x lottery wins, or 10x fifth places?